# Start multiple Firefox tabs (with 5 seconds interval) Minimized From Bash script

Tags: linux, bash, firefox, background-process, window-management

I want to open several tabs from a particular domain each with different assets  as defined in a bash script. To avoid getting banned from the server, I open tabs with an interval of 5 seconds as follows:

```
for ((i = 0; i < nWebsite; i = i + 1)); do
    (firefox -new-tabs "${WebsiteString[i]}" > /dev/null 2>&1 &)
    sleep 5
done
```

But, unfortunately, whenever a new tab is opened, the focus shift to the firefox and due to multiple tabs that I want to open it keeps happening for a long duration.

How can I open every tab in the above for loop minimized?

---

I tried the following:

```
for ((i = 0; i < nWebsite; i = i + 1)); do
    (firefox -new-tab "${WebsiteString[i]}" > /dev/null 2>&1 &)
    xdotool getactivewindow windowminimize
    sleep 5
done
```

But this doesn't solve the problem, as the focus still shifts to the new window, which is then minimized.

---

Although I asked for Firefox, but it would be great if the solution works for google-chrome as well!

Answer (score 0):

I *think* the solution is that you are not saving your current active window ID.

From [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277738/wmctrl-to-open-window-without-focus)

```
xdotool getactivewindow > ~/.window_id
for ((i = 0; i < nWebsite; i = i + 1)); do
    (firefox -new-tab "${WebsiteString[i]}" > /dev/null 2>&1 &)
    xdotool windowfocus $(cat ~/.window_id)
    xdotool windowactivate $(cat ~/.window_id)
    sleep 5
done
```

Of course, that will do it for each iteration of the loop. If you want it just
when the loop is done (after 25 seconds) put the xdtools outside the loop, like so:

```
xdotool getactivewindow > ~/.window_id
for ((i = 0; i < nWebsite; i = i + 1)); do
    (firefox -new-tab "${WebsiteString[i]}" > /dev/null 2>&1 &)
    sleep 5
done
xdotool windowfocus $(cat ~/.window_id)
xdotool windowactivate $(cat ~/.window_id)
```

Comment: It didn't work! The focus changes from terminal to browser, then back to terminal and this goes on every 5 seconds. Also, does it work in cases when the browser was previously open or not?

Comment: Ok, then put the xdtool outside of the loop. I will add an answer. Also, note, I am just trying to solve your focus problem, and I was not working on open every tab minimized.

Comment: In the suggested changes, the focus has still shifted to the browser from the terminal, and the focus returns to the terminal only after all URL are loaded. This is not intended, as I don't want to lose focus from terminal.

Comment: I do not think, with the current tools built into most window managers under linux, that you can not loose focus for a short time. Remove "sleep 5" and see if that is to your satisfaction, OR, force a fast focus refresh of your terminal, as [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80968/how-can-i-force-new-windows-to-open-in-background-without-focus) suggests.